# Динамическое создание директив с AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Имеется следующий набор объектов, которые представляют собой некое описание директив:

```
var directives = [{template: '<directive-one />', data: {message: 'qwerty'}},
                  {template: '<directive-one />', data: {message: 'asdfgh'}},       
                  {template: '<directive-two />', data: {message: 'zxcvbn'}}];
```

*template* - шаблон вызова директивы;

*data* - данные, которые должны быть переданы в директиву.

Директивы *directive-one, directive-two* реализованы (имеют изолированный scope).

Каким образом можно реализовать динамическое создание этих директив?

Comment: Примерно то, что мне было нужно: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19224028/add-directives-from-directive-in-angularjs/19228302#19228302

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно определить `link` для директивы-обертки и там скомпилировать шаблоны. Что-то ничего умнее для связывания `scope` на ум не приходит:

```
var directive = scope.$eval(iAttrs.directive);
scope.data = directive.data;
```

```js
// Code goes here
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    var directives = [{
      template: '<directive-one data="data"/>',
      data: {
        message: 'qwerty'
      }
    }, {
      template: '<directive-two data="data"/>',
      data: {
        message: true
      }
    }, {
      template: '<directive-thr data="data"/>',
      data: {
        message: 126
      }
    }];
    $scope.directives = directives;
  }
]);

app.directive('myCompiller', ['$compile',
  function($compile) {
    var link = function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
      var directive = scope.$eval(iAttrs.directive);
      scope.data = directive.data;
      iElement.html(directive.template);
      $compile(iElement.contents())(scope);
    };
    return {
      replace: true,
      link: link
    };
  }
]);

app.directive('directiveOne', function() {
  var template = '<div>directiveOne : <input type="text" ng-model="data.message"/></div>';
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: template,
    scope: {
      'data': '='
    }
  };
});

app.directive('directiveTwo', function() {
  var template = '<div>directiveTwo : <input type="checkbox" ng-model="data.message"/></div>';
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: template,
    scope: {
      'data': '='
    }
  };
});

app.directive('directiveThr', function() {
  var template = '<div>directiveThr : {{data.message | currency:"$"}}</div>';
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: template,
    scope: {
      'data': '='
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.3" data-semver="1.4.3" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">

  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">

    <div class="container">
      <div>directives[0] :
        <input type="text" ng-model="directives[0].data.message" />
      </div>
      <div>directives[1] :
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="directives[1].data.message" />
      </div>
      <div>directives[2] :
        <input type="number" ng-model="directives[2].data.message" />
      </div>
      <hr/>
      <my-compiller directive="dr" ng-repeat="dr in directives"></my-compiller>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

- [Creating Custom Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)
- [HTML Compiler](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я в итоге сделал директиву, которая создаёт другие директивы по переданным в неё данным.

Comment: @DenisBednov, интересно, как реализовали вы.

Comment: @DenisBednov, Сударь, если Вас не затруднит, извольте опубликовать свой код. У меня сейчас как раз есть множество вопросов по созданию директив, и на эти вопросы у меня нет ответа.